# Replacing text chunk in file using positions with python

Tags: python

I have a large text file and I know the positions of the parts of the code that I would like to change. I am trying to do something similar to this:

```
infile = open('file.txt', 'rb')
infile.seek(start_position)
text_lenght = end_position - start_position
print(infile.read(text_lenght).upper(), file = infile)
```

The file is supposed to be modified in place and overwrite the previous text file. Is there a way to do this?

Hope I explained myself clear enough.

Comment: Is the data to replace the same length as the data you're overwriting?

Comment: Yes, it is of the exact same length.

Comment: Search terms `python modify a file in place site:stackoverflow.com` produces relevant SO Q&A's. Variations of those terms should produce other useful Q&A's.

Answer (score 1):

```
 infile = open('file.txt', 'r+')
 infile.seek(seek_position)
 infile.write(text_to_write)
```